# Error while reading CSV containing Korean language

Tags: r, read.csv, korean-nlp

I am trying to read CSV file in which one column contain korean text using below lines

```
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale = "Korean")
old <- read.csv("Past-Korean.csv", encoding = "utf-8",header=T,na.strings=c(""))
```

But I am getting error

```
Error in type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, numerals = numerals,  : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<ec><8b><9c>ìŠ¤í…œ ë¬¸ì œ'
```

I am able to read Chinese and Japanese using similar sytax, but facing issue while reading Korean 
Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In absence of sample data I can't test it but would you mind trying this approach?

```r
library(readr)
locale("ko")

df <- read_csv(file = "your_csv_file.csv", 
               locale = locale(date_names = "ko", encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

Comment: This is awesome. Just wanted to reconfirm that we can't use earlier method for reading CSV file containing korean characheters. Or can we use above method to read other language data like Japanese, Chinese, French, English etc..

Comment: Glad that it helped! You can use this code snippet to read any language. see `?date_names_langs()` for list of locale.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help will try this